# After getting a new long lived access_token, would the old long lived access_token work?

Tags: java, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

Lets say I have an existing long lived access_token (say T1). Now, for the same user I generate a short lived access_token. With the help the short lived token I fetch the new long lived access_token (say T2).
My question is, would the T1 continue working (please assume that it's expiry has not elapsed)?

Comment: Why don’t you just test it for yourself? Not that complicated, so do it and let us know what you found out :-)

Comment: @CBroe: I understand that its fairly simple to test once you get two different tokens. But, I could not get two different tokens. Every time I tried, it was returning me same access_token.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation for the offline_access deprecation](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/):

> The returned access_token will have a fresh long-lived expiration
>   time, however, the access_token itself may or may not be the same as
>   the previously granted long-lived access_token.

Comment: Thanks lgy for reply. I've also read this previously. It does not say anything about the validity of previous token. It is emphasizing that the return token may or may not be same. But, what about the validity of previous token?